# Defined name in excel's chart doesn't work

Tags: excel, dynamic, charts, range

I need to input a range of data into my chart, which will be changing over time. I think that defined names will help me, but even when I follow tutorials, it does not work for me. I have problem at the moment, when I trying set the defined name into the chart.

I using the following tutorial: [TechRepublic - Two Ways to Build Dynamic Charts in Excel](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/two-ways-to-build-dynamic-charts-in-excel/).
I tried changing `counta` to `count2` and `,` to `;` but it still didn't work.

When I attempt to add the name of my range into the chart's labels, it returns an error.

I tried to delete the `=` sign from the beginning. Names were created just for the sheet, and there are no strange characters in the names. But still nothing.

For a range I'm using this code (for SmithSeries):

```
=OFFSET(DynamicChart1!$B$2;0;0;COUNT2(DynamicChart1!$B:$B)-1)
```

It was originally:

```
=OFFSET(DynamicChart1!$B$2,0,0,COUNTA(DynamicChart1!$B:$B)-1)
```

And into the chart as X I'm using:

```
=List1!SmithSeries
```

Excel returns an error message that says that I may need to check the formula. I've followed several tutorials with the same incorrect result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I realized, that the problem was in type of Office.
When I tried to make dynamic range for chart in other PS with other type of Office, it works there.
Good to know is that, when you make even blank sheet frm ottehr office, you can edit it even in the old one and it still work.